# Invalid hook call on npm module

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, react-hooks, babeljs

First of all link to the repo: https://github.com/vmarchesin/react-konami-code

You should be able to build it (make sure to uncomment the export on `src/index.js`) and link to your project. It is also possible to try it out using `npm i -S react-konami-code@2.0.0-beta.0` and get the error for the hook. I removed the hook from `2.0.0-beta.1` because it's broken.

#### Description of the problem

I created a custom hook for my npm module and it doesn't work after being published or using it as a module. I suspect the issue is with how webpack bundles it but I can't solve it.

#### Steps taken

- I made sure to declare `react` and `react-dom` as externals in my webpack config.

```json
externals: [
  {
    react: {
      root: 'React',
      commonjs2: 'react',
      commonjs: 'react',
      amd: 'react',
    },
    'react-dom': {
      root: 'ReactDOM',
      commonjs2: 'react-dom',
      commonjs: 'react-dom',
      amd: 'react-dom',
    },
  },
],
```

- Declared `react` and `react-dom` as `peerDependencies` in the `package.json`

```json
"peerDependencies": {
  "react": "^16.13.1",
  "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
},
```

- The hook is working. If I declare it and use it, it works. If I import it from the module (or use npm link) it doesn't. Here is the code for the hook:

```js
import { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from 'react';

export default (action, {
  code = [38, 38, 40, 40, 37, 39, 37, 39, 66, 65],
} = {}) => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState([]);

  const onKeyUp = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      const newInput = input;
      newInput.push(e.keyCode);
      newInput.splice(-code.length - 1, input.length - code.length);

      setInput(newInput);

      if (newInput.join('').includes(code.join(''))) {
        action();
      }
    },
    [input, setInput, code, action],
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp);
    };
  }, [onKeyUp]);
};
```

- I am not calling the hook inside a class component.

I am using `webpack@4.43.0` as well as `babel@7` and `babel-loader@8.1.0`.

Here is how I export the index file for the webpack build:

```js
import Konami from './Konami';

export default Konami; // disregard this, it works
export { default as useKonami } from './useKonami'; // this doesn't work
```

Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvluI.png) and transcript of the error:

> Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be
> called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen
> for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Comment: I tried most of the solutions available here https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16029, nothing worked.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this, as i am also getting the same error.

Comment: @Optimus Please try my answer below, if still needed.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, tried all the solutions and none of them worked.

**The solution to this is**, we need to configure **Webpack** to essentially ignore React as part of the production bundle along with peer dependency.

To do this, add below lines in `webpack.config.js`:

```
externals: {
   "react": "commonjs react",
   "react-dom": "commonjs react-dom",
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error message while trying to import a react component from a npm package that I built. As the explanation of the error message suggests, this was propably a case of a [duplicate React](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#duplicate-react).

The important part concerning the error message is to bundle `react` and `react-dom` as ***external imports***, so that the react of the parent project is being used, instead of using a second, that is a **duplicate React**.

I solved that by building my npm package with [rollup.js](https://rollupjs.org/), following this [guide](https://blog.logrocket.com/the-complete-guide-to-publishing-a-react-package-to-npm/) basically.

My resulting rollup.config.js:

```
import pkg from './package.json'
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';

export default {
  input: 'src/index.js',
  output: [
    {
      file: pkg.main,
      format: 'cjs',
      exports: 'named',
      sourcemap: true,
      strict: false
    }
  ],
  plugins: [babel({ babelHelpers: 'bundled' })],
  external: ['react', 'react-dom']
}
```

You need the following dev-dependencies in your npm package (assuming you also have to transpile with babel):

```
npm i -D rollup babel-core @rollup/plugin-babel
```

You can bundle with rollup like this:

```
// add that to your package.json
"scripts": {
  "build": "rollup -c",
  "start": "rollup -c -w"  // for watching changes
},
```

With `npm link` it is even possible to get a hot-reload in the parent project for the packaged react component you are developing, without any npm publishing. Yay.

Comment: "duplicate react" issue for me also. Moved react and react-native from dependencies/devDependencies into peerDependencies in my separate NPM omponent/package and all was good (after then deleting all node_modules, running yarn etc).

Comment: Adding react to external in my rollup config fixed my problem and make my package even smaller. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues here which might cause that error what you see on the console:

1. Not importing `React` so breaking the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) - [Only Call Hooks from React Functions](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions).
2. Also the issue can come from you don't have a named component here.

So I would include `React` as the following:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
```

Also you can try to export it as the following:

```
export default function ComponentName (action, {
  code = [38, 38, 40, 40, 37, 39, 37, 39, 66, 65],
} = {}) {
   // your component code
}
```

Or if you want to still use arrow function then:

```
const ComponentName = (action, {
  code = [38, 38, 40, 40, 37, 39, 37, 39, 66, 65],
} = {}) => {
   // your component code
}

export default ComponentName;
```

You can refer to this article: 
[**Do not use anonymous functions to construct React functional components**](https://medium.com/@stevemao/do-not-use-anonymous-functions-to-construct-react-functional-components-c5408ec8f4c7).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the insights. I added `React` as part of the import and replaced the anonymous arrow function to a named function for the default export. After clearing both `node_modules` (module and test app) and recreating the `npm link` the error still persists.

Comment: @vmarchesin If still needed, please try the solution I suggested in my answer below.